# MD5 - Chosen Prefix Collision Attack

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, md5

Given 2 messages $m_1$ and $m_2$, in a chosen prefix attack, we want to find $s_1$ and $s_2$ such that:

$\text{MD5}(m_1 || s_1) = \text{MD5}(m_2 || s_2)$

Are $s_1$ and $s_2$ found by brute force or are there some rule(s) to construct $s_1$ and $s_2$ based on $m_1$ and $m_2$?

Comment: Generally for these kind of attacks the $m$ and $s$ input consist of one or more blocks. The size of these blocks is determined by the internal block size of the cipher, which, for MD5, is 512 bit. Brute forcing a 512 bit block would take $2^{512} / 2 = 2^{511}$ tries on average. That's a calculation that will *never* finish (even if we take into account that it takes a very long time for black holes to vaporize due to Hawking radiation :P )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is due to the Stevens et. al's work ;

- [Chosen-prefix collisions for MD5 and applications](https://documents.epfl.ch/users/l/le/lenstra/public/papers/lat.pdf),  2012.

They showed that, with an approximately $2^{39}$ calls to the MD5 compression function, it is possible, for any chosen $m_1$ and $m_2$, to **construct** $s_1$ and $s_2$ such that $$\text{MD5} (m_1\mathbin\|s_1) = \text{MD5} (m_2\mathbin\|s_2)$$

They also gave examples for colliding documents, software integrity checking, etc ...

Comment: so... it's nearly bruteforce

Comment: @Pacerier far from the brute-force.